# How do I use more than one fxml with javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Currently, my main javaFX main class looks something like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private AnchorPane rootLayout;
private Shell shl = new Shell();;
@FXML
private PasswordField pass;
@FXML
private TextField user;
@FXML
private String description;
@FXML
private String title;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("WorkFlow Manager");
    initRootLayout();
}

/**
 * root layout (base layout).
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("LoginMenu.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);                                    
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void toDoLayout() {
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Todo.fxml"));
        AnchorPane toDo = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);

    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @return primaryStage
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@FXML
private void login(ActionEvent event) {
    if(user.getText()!=null && pass.getText()!=null){
        shl.login(user.getText(),pass.getText());
        System.out.printf("%s",shl.getCurrentUser());
        //toDoLayout(); I commented this out since it isn't working
    }
}
}
```

My first function, initRootLayout(), is working fine, loads the fxml as it's supposed to and executes the expected functions on action.

However, what I'm trying is to launch a new scene (replacing the login fxml scene). I tried to call the toDoLayout() function (it's commented out) as it would throw these exceptions everytime I clicked the button:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.iface.MainTerminal{
/C:/Users/a51217/workspace/wfmgr/bin/main/iface/Todo.fxml:9
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
  at main.iface.Main.toDoLayout(Main.java:59)
  at main.iface.Main.login(Main.java:84)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.iface.MainTerminal{
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at main.iface.Main.toDoLayout(Main.java:59)
    at main.iface.Main.login(Main.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.iface.MainTerminal{
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
```

EDIT: My Todo.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.iface.MainTerminal{">
   <children>
      <ListView layoutX="37.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="333.0" prefWidth="195.0" />
      <ScrollBar layoutX="37.0" layoutY="47.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="333.0" prefWidth="14.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="getTitle" layoutX="262.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="321.0" />
      <TextArea fx:id="getDescription" layoutX="262.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="247.0" prefWidth="321.0" />
      <Button layoutX="262.0" layoutY="355.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create Task" />
      <Button layoutX="351.0" layoutY="355.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Assign User to this Task" />
      <ScrollBar layoutX="262.0" layoutY="92.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="247.0" prefWidth="14.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

MainTerminal isn't my controller, I forgot to correct it. My Main is acting as the controller so I changed the 9th line to:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.iface.Main{">
```

After this change, the exceptions are the seem to be the same:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.iface.Main{
/C:/Users/a51217/workspace/wfmgr/bin/main/iface/Todo.fxml:9
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
  at main.iface.Main.toDoLayout(Main.java:59)
  at main.iface.Main.login(Main.java:84)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.iface.Main{
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at main.iface.Main.toDoLayout(Main.java:59)
    at main.iface.Main.login(Main.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.iface.Main{
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: It just looks like it can't find you controller class. What is on line 9 of ToDo.fxml?

Comment: I had this:
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.iface.MainTerminal{">

Comment: I edited the question, I think I answered what you asked @James_D

Comment: And you don't think that stray `{` in the `fx:controller` attribute might be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so since it was generated by javafx scene builder and when I delete it I get a compiler warning. I run the application without it and it didn't throw any exceptions. Yet, the scene didn't change at all, which still doesn't solve my problem. @James_D

Comment: The exception clearly states it can't find the controller class. Additionally, your `toDoLayout()` method creates a `Scene` but then does nothing with it. You need to display it in the stage. Finally, there is something very weird with your code as you seem to be using your `Application` subclass as a controller, which doesn't really work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot I didn't develop the toDoLayout() method! It clearly states it can't be found but the class exists and is even in the same package, I don't get it... About the Application subclass, I extended it to be able to override the start method, I thought that was the way to implement javafx gui functions; is there another, better way?

Comment: Yes, you use an `Application` subclass with an overriden `start()` method to start up your application, but you should not use the same class as a controller; you should have the controller code in a separate class. (This isn't what's causing your issue, which is, again, because you somehow have the class name wrong, but it will cause problems later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is occurring because you have an extra `{` in the `fx:controller` attribute. This attribute should be set to the fully-qualified name of the controller class. Since `{` is not a legal character in a class name, `fx:controller = "main.iface.MainTerminal{"` cannot possibly be correct.

Assuming your controller class is `MainTerminal` and is in a package called `main.iface`, the correct attribute setting is `fx:controller = "main.iface.MainTerminal"`.

Additionally, your `toDoLayout()` method just creates a `Scene` containing the UI defined in ToDo.fxml, but doesn't do anything with that scene: you need to display it in a stage. So once you have fixed the `fx:controller` attribute, it will run without errors but not do anything until you also fix that code.

Finally, it looks like you are using your `Application` subclass as a controller for (at least?) one of your FXML files, as you have `@FXML`-annotated fields in it. Do **not** do this: it will be highly confusing. (What happens is that one instance of your `Main` class is created at startup for you, and then *another instance* is created by the `FXMLLoader` for whichever FXML file declares this as the controller. Some fields will be initialized in the first instance - `primaryStage` and `rootLayout` - and other fields (the `@FXML`-annotated ones) will be initialized in the second instance. It will be very very difficult to keep track of what is initialized and what is still `null`.) You should create the `Application` subclass just to start the application up, and then each FXML should have its own, separate, controller class.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will try to fix all the issues you have talked about to see if they are the root of the problem.